# The [H] doesnt change figure* placement, printed on page instead

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I'm trying to modify my figure placements, but the `[H]` (and `[!ht]`, etc) isn't working.  It has no effect on the figure placement, and I get the text "[H]" added just before the image.

MCWE:

```
\documentclass{mn2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure*}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{fig}
    \caption{Some Caption}
    \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure*}

\blindtext[10]

\blindtext[6]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

And I'm using TeXShop 3.6.1 on OSX 10.11.2

Comment: The `[H]` option is illegal for `figure*`.

Comment: @egreg... okay, how do you achieve the same effect with `figure*`?

Comment: @egreg also, while a normal `figure` ***is*** placed in the correct position, the `[H]` is still just printed on the page....

Comment: mn2e class isn't in texlive it seems? I do not have it.  perhaps it is incompatible with float  package (which adds `H`), there is no way to get an H effect with figure*, what would you want it to do?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ... I would want it to place the figure above the text, as in the `.tex` document....

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix that is the default, H in a single column document puts the float mid page not at the top.

Comment: texlive has a mnras class which ctan lists as having `legacy\mn2e.cls     v2.2 of mn2e.cls (deprecated)` is that the one you are using? http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mnras/README

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mn2e` and its replacement `mnras` class disable the float options. As with many publisher classes they intentionally remove options from the author to enforce a house style.